# Use regular expression in qmake file

Tags: regex, qt, qmake

I have this regex checking for version number working in my cpp file

```
QString parseVersion()
{
   // https://regex101.com/r/nFMiA0/1
   QRegularExpression re{R"((?:(\d+\.[.\d]*\d+)))"};
   if(auto match = re.match(VERSION); match.hasMatch()){
      return match.captured();
   }
   return "0.0.0";
}
```

I'd like to move it inside pro file, something like

```
# pseudo code
contains(VERSION, ((?:(\d+\.[.\d]*\d+)))){
   // yada yada
}
```

suppose `VERSION` with a string like `yada-1.2.3`

How could I use a regex inside a pro file?

Comment: I don't know if you have to use capture groups, but you could also get the same matches using `\d+(?:\.\d+)+`

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#contains-variablename-value): *It is possible to specify a regular expression for parameter value.* `contains(OSDISTRO, \d+\.[.\d]*\d+){` should work same as your regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn't work for string like `yada-1.2.3`

Comment: Ok, does `.*\d+(?:\.\d+)+` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does! If you write an answer with that I'm going to accept it. Maybe could you explain the previous attempts didn't work? I'm a little confused about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`contains` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#contains-variablename-value):

> It is possible to specify a regular expression for parameter value.

In your case, you can use

```cpp
contains(OSDISTRO, .*\d+(?:\.\d+)+) {
...
}
```

Here, the pattern is `.*\d+(?:\.\d+)+` and it matches

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+` - one or more repetitions of a dot and one or more digits.

This also means, the pattern must match the whole string, that is why the previous attempts failed.

Comment: What if I would to extracto only the non-greedy substring?

Comment: @Moia From what I understand in the docs, the method only returns true or false.